# Concise way to say, "A difference in exposure between my peers and I"

Tags: single-word-requests, concision

What I'm looking for, is a specific word in the vein of:

> I feel an *exposural* divide between my peers and I

'Exposural' isn't a word, but I wish to express that I feel a difference in exposure to new technologies, between my peers and I.

1. Does such a word exist?
2. Is there a more concise/more elegant way to say what I want to?

Comment: Would you care to say what you mean by exposure first? I mean, you could be talking about publicity in the media, less probably shutter speed and less likely still hypothermia or having a lot of space below your feet on the wall of El Capitan, but who ca be sure?

Comment: Are you saying one of you is getting more sun?  Or is someone's picture overexposed?  Or it there a difference in the amount of clothing you're wearing?

Comment: Everyone else in my class was smoking marijuana too, but I got busted and wound up on the front page; as the posterboy for delinquent youth?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. The question has been edited to hopefully clear that up.

Comment: Of course the fact is that whatever word you choose, the sentence is ungrammatical and makes the speaker look silly. Funny nobody mentioned that yet.

Comment: Well, @John, he didn't ask *that*. ;) PS to geekyrudh: say "*I've had more experience with <these technologies> than my peers*".

Comment: @JohnLawler Could you please point out why? How do I improve? English is my second language, so I'm not as familiar with the finer points of sentence structure..

Thank you, Dan Bron!

Comment: This is not a fine point. This is a basic point. _Between you and I_ should be _between you and me_; objects of prepositions are objective forms. Even when they are conjoined. _You_ has no objective form, so you can't tell; but _I_ does. This is like saying _between I and she_ or _for I_.

Comment: Not to mention, an _exposural divide_ brings to mind a rip in one's pants.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the word 'experiential'.

eg. "I feel an experiential divide between my peers and myself."

Note use of "myself" ( object ) rather than "I" ( subject ). Why that change? Think of it like this: would you say "I see I" or "I see myself"? ;-)